# Using rename command to rename first part of a file

Tags: directory, filenames, rename

I have three files in a directory (in mac-osx terminal) say

```
INIT_Struc1
INIT_Struc2
INIT_Struc3
```

which I need to rename as

```
FINAL_Struc1
FINAL_Struc2
FINAL_Struc3
```

When I use the rename command (installed through homebrew) as

```
rename -n 's/\INIT_$/FINAL_/' INIT_*
```

it does not rename the files. What am I doing wrong with the rename command that fails to rename the files.

Comment: Drop the `$`, it means *end of string*, but the string doesn't end, yet.

Comment: Leave the `-n` flag: no action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. this rename will replace `INIT_` as final part of filename. 
   (`foo.INIT_` would be renamed to `foo.FINAL_`, on REGEXP paradign '`$`' is end of line '`^`' beginning etc ... )
2. `\I` lead to an unknow switch for rename

try

```
 rename -n s/INIT_/FINAL_/ $(find . -print )
```

for a preview. 
where

- `-n` flag is for preview
- `$(find . -print )` will go down directory (from local dir), LHS(*) of rename will filter name.

  rename  s/INIT_/FINAL_/ $(find . -print )

no need for quotes, if no funny name.

(*) stand for Left Hand Side.

Comment: right without the -n

Comment: That worked, is it because $ sign indicates the end of string (or filename) ?

Comment: This fails if I try to rename sub-directories. Can you please update the answer as to how I can rename sub-directories as well.